# Co-first author dilemma?

Tags: phd, united-states, biology

My PI wants to put me as co-first author, listed second, on a paper where I've done about 5-10% of the work. I didn't come up with any of the project, or do any of the writing or analysis, just helped make certain things the first author asked me to.

I believe the other student (first author) who did the majority of the work on the project isn't necessarily happy about this, but hasn't said anything to me about it personally. However, even if they did oppose it to my PI, the PI would probably just disregard what they say. PI is very senior here and has a lot of power.

I feel kind of bad about the situation. The paper will soon be submitted to a very high impact factor journal. Should I say anything to the PI about this, or just accept being placed as co-first author listed second?

Are there pros and cons to declining the co-author status if I feel I don't deserve it, vs accepting it and going along with my PI? Will me being listed as co-first author listed second, hurt the true first author in any way?

Comment: did the PI give any reason why you should be the co-first author?

Comment: Perhaps you are underestimating your own contribution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! My PI said that it's the best case scenario for me and will help my career, and that it's the first listed author that matters most anyway. 

I did think a lot about my contribution, and I honestly know that I did not contribute as much as the first author.

Answer (score 3):

> Will me being listed as co-first author listed second, hurt the true first author in any way?

It's unlikely that this will truly hurt the other first author in a direct way. At the end of the day, authorship, even first-authorship, is not a pie that gets smaller the more people share it.

That said, as you can see from the many, *many* questions around authorship and authorship order on this site, this is an emotional topic for many academics, and it's certainly possible that the first author feels like something has been "stolen" from him. If you want to ensure good future collaborations with this person I would make sure that they are truly on board with your author order, and not just going along with it because the famous professor said so (and if that's the case I would decline and just be a regular second author). Overall, I have found that being gracious about these things is a good long-term strategy.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll have to talk with the first author somehow. We've never talked about it and I just felt like it could be awkward. When you say "unlikely that this will truly hurt" - could you talk about some ways, however unlikely, it could potentially affect them? Other than the possible emotional aspect you mention.

I guess my PI made it sound like, the co-first author thing won't affect the listed first author at all which is "the position that really matters", but will only serve to help the second listed author.

Comment: @AJ445 idk ... Maybe he applies somewhere where they have a "weighting scheme" for publication output that takes co-first-authors into account? I have never heard of something like this, but I have learned the hard way that academia is way too varied for anything to ever be truly certain.

Comment: "At the end of the day, authorship, even first-authorship, is not a pie that gets smaller the more people share it." I'm somewhat surprised by this, because I can't remember even a single paper where it was clear to me as reader that the second author is "co-first author", so I'm not sure this is visible, and if it's not (or only with difficulty) visible, any benefits from first authorship may indeed not be distributed equally among co-first authors but rather favour the author actually listed first. (It may depend on the field, region etc.)

Comment: @AJ445 "I guess my PI made it sound like, the co-first author thing won't affect the listed first author at all which is "the position that really matters"" - I'd think that it's likely the PI is right about this.